# how to inject javascript in UIWebview on native buttonclick

Tags: iphone, ipad

```
  script =@"<HTML>\n"
    "<HEAD>\n"
    "<TITLE></TITLE>\n"
    "<script language=\"javascript\">\n"
    "function openQuote(){\n"
      "  quoteForm.submit();}\n"
    "</script>\n"
   "</HEAD>\n"
    "<BODY>\n"
    "<form name=\"quoteForm\" url=\"http://localHost/Pages/CaseManagement.aspx?Page=CaseActivity\">\n"
    //    <input type="text" id="caseID" value="CA0S491"/>
   " </form>\n"
   " <input type=\"button\" onClick=\"openQuote();\" value=\"Click Me\"/>\n"
    "</BODY>"
   " </HTML>\n";

    I need to inject javascript on native button click
```

Answer (score 1):

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];

Comment: i need to load this script on webview on button click loadRequest

Comment: Sorry, but do you want to do execute a Javascript on touch of a Native Button, or want to call a native Action by clicking an HTML Button?

Comment: I want to inject the javaScript into UIWebView On native button click and reload the url webView with script parameter's and url!

Comment: Do you want to inject javascript see above, e.g. [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"openQuote();"]; if you want to load an URL use loadRequest.